# jQuery .then() vs simple sequential functions

Tags: jquery, get

Can someone explain the difference between:

```
$.get( "test.php" ).then(
  function() {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "test.php"
    });
  }
);
```

and

```
$.get( "test.php" );
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php"
});
```

In my specific case I need to make a GET call before I can make an AJAX POST call (*to the same url*) to fix [a bug](http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2013/making-xhr-request-to-https-domains-with-winjs/) in IE / Edge.

Comment: In first example, whatever is contained within `then()` will be executed once the `get` call succeeds and finishes. In second example, both `ajax` and `get` will be executed pretty much at the same time without waiting on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX requests are event-based. They are created and the javascript continues executing. When the AJAX state changes, that's when the callback function executes.

The difference in the two scripts is detailed below:

```
                             //  Execution         On GET Success
$.get( "test.php" ).then(    //  | Creates GET
  function() {               //  | Adds Callback   | Triggers Callback
    $.ajax({                 //  |                 | Creates POST
      method: "POST",        //  |                 |
      url: "test.php"        //  |                 |
    });                      //  |                 |
  }                          //  |                 |
);                           //  | 
                             // \_/

                             //  Execution
$.get( "test.php" );         //  | Creates GET
$.ajax({                     //  | Creates POST
  method: "POST",            //  |
  url: "some.php"            //  |
});                          //  |
                             // \_/
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That definitely makes sense. So normally, the javascript will always continue executing after `.get()` regardless of whether it receives a response or not?

Comment: @Ewout Yes. It is asynchronous (meaning it won't wait for a response before continuing execution). When a response happens, the state of the call will change which will trigger an event which will be used to fire callbacks, etc. If you specify `async: false` in the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), then it will be synchronous and _will_ wait. It will be in a [busy waiting state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) where nothing else can be done.